# Failed to set the 'value' property on 'HTMLInputElement': VUEJS

Tags: html, vue.js

Error : DOMException: Failed to set the 'value' property on 'HTMLInputElement': This input element accepts a filename, which may only be programmatically set to the empty string.

Facing this error in Vue.js while taking an input file from input box and uploading that file on AWS S3 on selecting.

So below is the code for the said .

```
<div class="vx-col md:w-1/2 w-full mt-5">
      <vs-input class="w-full form-group" label="Brand Logo" type="file" name="logo" id="logo" ref="logo" accept="image/*" :value="this.stepOneProps.logo" v-on:change="handleLogoUpload" />
    </div>

methods: {
  async handleLogoUpload(event) {
    const file = event.target.files[0];
    this.filename = file.name; // set the filename variable
    const params = {
      Bucket: 'logo-bb',
      Key: file.name,
      Body: file,
      ACL: 'public-read',
    };
    try {
      const data_logo = await s3.upload(params).promise();
      this.stepOneProps.logo = data_logo.Location;
      
      console.log('Uploaded logo link:', data_logo.Location);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  },
}
```

The below is the screenshot of the input box

[image: Image 1]

here in the input box when i select a file and move to another input box that is not working because of the error.

Thanks in Advance.

here in the input box when i select a file and move to another input box that is not working because of the error.

Comment: remove `:value="this.stepOneProps.logo"` it's not needed/allowed

Comment: @LawrenceCherone when i remove that the file is uploading to s3 but when i move to other element the input box does not show file name and and it shows No file selected but the file is already uploaded on s3.

Comment: after upload or on editing view etc, switch the input out for an element which shows the filename (or the actual image), simply put, it's not possible set a value on a `type="file"`, what I do is just have a button or placeholder image, then on click trigger a hidden file input, then on select replace the placeholder image

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Cool. Working thanks for your Time.